# Why Matplotlib font_manager keep matching an available font?

Tags: matplotlib

I suppose that when Matplotlib font_manager could NOT find the font the user specified on the platform, it would try to match it to a 'close' font. In our system, we checked currently available fonts for Matplotlib on all platforms then picked up a common one ('DejaVu Sans Mono') which had been installed on all places. We defined the font in util function:

```
font = {'family': 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'weight': 'normal', 'size': 16}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
```

To my surprise, when I execute the plotting code, I still got lots of font_manager.findfont message. The sample piece is as follow:

```
2019-06-07 14:20:46.169 (963    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono.ttf') with score of 0.050000
2019-06-07 14:20:46.169 (963    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono.ttf') with score of 0.050000
2019-06-07 14:20:46.272 (963    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=5.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono.ttf') with score of 0.050000
2019-06-07 14:20:46.272 (963    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=5.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono.ttf') with score of 0.050000
2019-06-07 14:20:48.195 (966    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=11.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono.ttf') with score of 0.050000
2019-06-07 14:20:48.195 (966    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=11.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono.ttf') with score of 0.050000
2019-06-07 14:20:49.686 (967    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=bold:stretch=normal:size=22.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf') with score of 0.000000
2019-06-07 14:20:49.686 (967    MB) DEBUG [23116| font_manager.findfont]: findfont: Matching :family=DejaVu Sans Mono:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=bold:stretch=normal:size=22.0 to DejaVu Sans Mono (u'/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf') with score of 0.000000
```

What should I do to avoid this issue? Thanks a lot.